# Why does compiling a function with ConstantArray give an error when used in parallel?

Tags: parallelization, compile

Here is a sample compiled function:

```
f := Compile[{x}, ConstantArray[0., 10]; x^2, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
        Parallelization->True,  CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

Using with a single argument works fine:

```
f[10.0] = 100.0;
```

But using it in parallel gives an error message:

```
f[{10.0,20.0}]
```

> `CompiledFunction::pext:` Instruction 1 in «original function» calls ordinary *Mathematica* code that can be evaluated on only one thread at a time. >>

The problem is in the `ConstantArray[0.,10]`, which is not even being used. Replacing it with `Table[0.,{10}]` fixes the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: The [general consensus](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192/52) is that new questions should not be tagged [tag:bugs] until there is confirmation by the community, at large.

Comment: `ConstantArray` is not compilable, even though this is not very apparent from looking at the instructions (`f[[6]]`), but it can be seen with `CompilePrint` - there is a callback to `MainEvaluate`. This is what the message warns about. Use `Table` to get the fully compiled code.

Comment: Side comment: you should use `f =`, not `f := `, otherwise `f` will be recompiled every time it's called

Comment: Not a bug, for the reason Leonid states. Top-level evaluation is not thread-safe, so these calls cannot be parallelized.

Comment: For more on what can compile see: List of compilable functions at: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions/19194#19194

Comment: A bit of extra info on `CompilePrint`:  it will show you a human readable form of the byte code that `Compile` compiles to.  The C code is generated from this byte code as well, so it's useful to look at it even if your target is C (it's easier to read than the C Mathematica generates).  To use `CompilePrint`, you'll need to load ``<<CompiledFunctionTools` `` first, then `CompilePrint[f]`.

Comment: Is (incorrectly) calling something a bug reason for closure nowadays? It's clear this isn't a bug, so we should edit that, but otherwise I don't see a reason for closing this question. This is certainly not too localized as it is not very specific to a certain application of the user. The line of code looks very generic.

Comment: I agree with @SjoerdC.deVries... this seems to have been closed a little too eagerly. True, this is not a bug and OP also seems to have found the solution (use `Table`), but not the reason _why_. This is certainly not in the same class of questions that show no effort and merely ask for something that's covered in the first line of the docs. This is a trap that one can easily fall into, and I knew about this (ConstantArray vs Table) only because Leonid pointed it out once in my answer. (I can understand if it were to be closed as a dupe of a "How do I find if X was actually compiled" question)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I suppose it could be TL if you think the meaning of the message is clear and obvious. IMO the question is reasonable since it is not explicitly documented anywhere (a) what functions are or are not compilable or (b) that top-level evaluation is not thread-safe.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Fully agree. I provided a CW answer below. Care to see if it needs improvement?

Comment: Thank you all for the support and the useful feedback, and sorry about the 'bug' labelling. ConstantArray seemed like a simple function, and I have found other seemingly more complicated functions which compiled fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer, compiled [sic] from the comments above, arises from the following considerations:

1. Not all functions can be compiled. [This extremely interesting thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/57) discusses this. `ConstantArray` can't be compiled; `Table` can.
2. Functions that cannot be compiled will be dealt with via a call out to the top-level interpreter.
3. The *Mathematica* interpreter is not thread-safe, or at least not reentrant.
4. Your code asks for parallelization, which is accomplished in this case through multithreading.
5. The `Listable` attribute causes the call of `f[{1,2}]` to be interpreted as `{f[1],f[2]}` which *Mathematica* attempts to parallelize.

The `CompiledFunction::pext` message is produced here to warn you that parallelization could not be accomplished as a result of the five facts mentioned above.